# ActiveMq, what happens if Client terminates before Ack

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have a persistent queue, non-transacted, client-acknowledge, the consumers read with jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=50000

and once a consumer processes a message, it ack's the message.

If the consumer reads the message, and before it can send an ack, the process terminates abruptly, what happens in ActiveMq?  (What ActiveMq parameters come into play here?)

How is that different than if the the consumer will take 10 minutes to process the message (so the consumer task is alive and working), how does ActiveMq know the message is still being worked on?  (Does it monitor the TCP/IP connection, if the connection dies, it assumes the message will not be Ack'ed?)

How do I determine if a message is a "poison pill", i.e. it makes the consumers crash?  (the redelivery count seems to be valid if the consumer task does not die; is there an internal counter in the message that says "it was been read n times without being successfully ack'ed?")

As an experiment, I sent 6 messages, one of them being a "poison pill" (kills the consumer before the consumer can send the ack), with 2 simultaneous consumers running (and automatically restarting consumers to bring the count to 2 whenever a consumer dies).  Looking at the queue (using jconsole, I enable jmx using broker.setUseJmx(true)), 4 messages were delivered, 2 are in-flight.  Why would there be 2 in-flight instead of just one?

I've been reading the ActiveMq and JMS specs for a while without clear/conclusive answers, so any insights on what parameters come into play, and if there are any known bugs, will be greatly useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is purely based on my understanding of JMS - may not be completely correct:

*If the consumer reads the message, and before it can send an ack, the process terminates abruptly, what happens in ActiveMq*

My understanding is that since this happens in the context of a session with the JMS provider, JMS provider knows if the session is no longer active or has failed and any message not acknowledged as part of the session will be redelivered when the session is re-established.

*How do I determine if a message is a "poison pill", i.e. it makes the consumers crash?*

Like you have mentioned, the JMS provider keeps track of the # of times the message was redelivered possibly in the header of the message

*4 messages were delivered, 2 are in flight*

Not sure about this point

Comment: This helped, thanks.  I think ActiveMq realizes if the TCP/IP connection is broken (and may even have an exit hook on the consumer side to do it even faster).  Those messages (whose consumer exited abruptly) are in fact being redelivered.

Comment: Poison Pill:  I verified that when my consumer crashes out, JMS does keep the # times the message was redelivered, so I can use it to determine if it's a "poison pill" message (if # retries exceeds x, I log it and ack it).  Code:             org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage amqMessage = (org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMessage) jmsMessage;
            int redeliveryCounter = amqMessage.getRedeliveryCounter();